# StorageFile read content while file is in use by another process

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, file-storage

Currently I am using MetroLog. It uses a file stream to log info into the log file.

Is there a possibility to read the content of the StorageFile while it is in use by MetroLog's file stream

```
using (var randomAccessStream = await localFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
   ...
}
```

this code will cause an `Access Denied` exception. The file exists and it looks like it has the correct rights because it works if I disable logging.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution is the following (all my code is placed in the device implementation, not in the pcl):

At initialization of Metrolog save the Streaming file target for later purposes:

```
private static StreamingFileTarget _target;
...
LogManagerFactory.DefaultConfiguration.AddTarget(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, _target);
```

Close all open files of file target before open/read the current logfile of Metrolog:

```
await _target.CloseAllOpenFiles();
your code...
```

The current logfile will be opened again at the next log command.